# How to push changes to github after jenkins build completes?

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I have a jenkins job that clones the repository from github, then runs the powershell script that increments the version number in the file. I'm now trying to publish that update file back to the original repository on github, so when developer pulls the changes he gets the latest version number.

I tried using Git Publisher in the post build events, and I can publish tags with no issues, but it doesn't seem to publish any files.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Found an answer myself, this blog helped: http://thingsyoudidntknowaboutjenkins.tumblr.com/post/23596855946/git-plugin-part-3

Basically need to execute:

```
git checkout master
```

before modifying any files

then

```
git commit -am "Updated version number"
```

after modified files

and then use **post build action of Git Publisher** with an option of Merge Results which will push changes to github on successful build.

Comment: @allprog - Does the git publisher work with the Git multiple scm plugin? It looks like it doesn't. In the case of Git multiple scm how do we push the changes to github? Thanks!

Comment: @Anand I'm afraid I can't help you. But if you have a question, go ahead and post it. :)

Answer (score 49):

The `git checkout master` of the [answer by Woland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19923066/1824669) isn't needed. Instead use the "Checkout to specific local branch" in the "Additional Behaviors" section to set the "Branch name" to master.

The `git commit -am "blah"` is still needed.

Now you can use the "Git Publisher" under "Post-build Actions" to push the changes.  Be sure to specify the "Branches" to push ("Branch to push" = master, "Target remote name" = origin).

"Merge Results" isn't needed.

Comment: Problem here is to push Tags... :( https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25389

Comment: there is also a problem if your workspace is provided from a former jenkins job, so the git repo is not set. Then you can not use the git publisher plugin.

Answer (score 12):

Once you set your Global Jenkins credentials, you can apply this step:

```
stage('Update GIT') {
  steps {
    script {
      catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'example-secure', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME')]) {
            def encodedPassword = URLEncoder.encode("$GIT_PASSWORD",'UTF-8')
            sh "git config user.email admin@example.com"
            sh "git config user.name example"
            sh "git add ."
            sh "git commit -m 'Triggered Build: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}'"
            sh "git push https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${encodedPassword}@github.com/${GIT_USERNAME}/example.git"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I have the secret defined, how can I use it in the script instead of passing user configuration id/password/email every time? 

For example while cloning the repo I use : 

git url : 'ssh://git@bitbucket:9999/abc/xyz.git', credentialsId: 'big-guid', branch: 'master'

Wondering how can I use credentials

Comment: Hi java_enthu,
  I'm not completely certain of the question; however, the "withCredentials" method calls any key-value credential and populates the script in scope.

Comment: Hi Jason, valid point. Got it working by withCredentials. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Nice solution if one needs to push to a different Git repo, otherwise one could use plugins `Git Publisher` or `Git Push` (plugins don't allow to choose URL). I use UI, exposing variables via "Build Environmant" section.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, the `"Checkout to specific local branch"` from Claus's answer isn't needed as well.

You can just do changes, execute `git commit -am "message"` and then use "Git Publisher" with "Branch to push" = `/refs/heads/master` (or develop or whatever branch you need to push to), "Target remote name" = origin.

Answer (score 7):

I followed the below Steps. It worked for me.

In Jenkins execute shell under Build, creating a file and trying to push that file from Jenkins workspace to GitHub.

[image]

Download Git Publisher Plugin and Configure as shown below snapshot.

[image]

Click on Save and Build. Now you can check your git repository whether the file was pushed successfully or not.