# Jenkins - GitHub Integration

Tags: jenkins, github

I try the below commands via Jenkins:

cd C:\Users\C51539A\Downloads\TestRepository

1. `git config --global user.name "Ajith-Raman"`
2. `git init (optional)`
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -m "Test Results Updated"`
5. `git checkout -b master (optional)`
6. git push -u origin master (Also tried "git push origin master",
                              "git push origin HEAD:master",
                              "git push origin HEAD:refs/remotes/origin/master")

Commands till commit succeed. But push is stuck. Kindly find the screenshot below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1rav.png)

Please help.

Note: git remote -v and git show-ref display the appropriate results.

Comment: what's the connection to jmeter ? remove this tag if not relevant

Comment: A Jmeter test is being executed here. Once the execution is complete. Results are committed to the local repository (Git). Pushed from there on (to GitHub).

Comment: But issue is irrelevant to JMeter no? JMeter test can be remove and issue will still exists

Comment: People who executed jmeter tests via Jenkins can reply (If faced this issue).

Comment: The commands work fine when not executed via jenkins.

Comment: Are you using github?

Comment: Is your remote configured?

Comment: @JRichardsz, Yes.

Comment: Master is configured. I succeed to push (manually). But the same done via Jenkins hangs.

Comment: Could you validate this command : `git remote -v` ?

Comment: It displays the origin. In my case,                                                              
origin https://github.com/Ajith-Raman/Sample_Repo.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/Ajith-Raman/Sample_Repo.git (push)

Answer (score 0):

"git checkout -b master" is used to create a new branch. So, you are getting master already exists. Remove -b and try git checkout master. This should resolve your problem.

Comment: Issue still exists. push is stuck.

Comment: All the commands work fine manually. But push fails (gets stuck) through jenkins.

Comment: try using GIT Publisher in post build action

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922435/how-to-push-changes-to-github-after-jenkins-build-completes      refer this link