# Semaphore CI: Push Back to Git

Tags: git, github, semaphore-ci

I want to build a [Semaphore CI](https://semaphoreci.com/) pipeline that checks out my branch, builds some artifacts and pushes these to another branch.

Specifically I'm writing [Sphinx docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/), and when their source merges to `main`, I want to build the HTML docs in this pipeline, and push the HTML to another branch, which [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) will ingest and host.

I can't find any info in Semaphore's docs on how to push back to my git repository.

This is a relatively common use case, with all the main competitors offering easy execution:

- Jenkins has a [Git Publisher plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922435/how-to-push-changes-to-github-after-jenkins-build-completes)
- GitHub Actions' checkout action lets [push using the same token used for checkout out](https://github.com/actions/checkout#push-a-commit-using-the-built-in-token) with no additional setup
- Bitbucket Pipelines [makes it really easy to push back to your repo](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/push-back-to-your-repository/)

Comment: I know nothing of Semaphore CI itself, but in general *build products* should not be stored in a  Git repository. Git is bad at that. Build products should be stored in what some call an "artifactory", a sort of library in which one stores, well, build products. That's the same idea, in many ways, as Git, but different in a couple of crucial ways, which is why Git is the wrong answer and some sort of artifactory is the right one. (I don't have any particular artifactory system in mind here but building one based on say Amazon S3 would be straightforward.)

Comment: Having taken a *very* brief look at the Semaphore CI pages, I have the vague impression that their guys understand this as well, and hence don't support "push build products to Git" because they already know that's the wrong approach...

Comment: My intention isn't to use git as a replacement artifact store, Github pages hosts a free static site for you by ingesting html from a docs folder. Sphinx let's you write your static site in markdown and generates the html for you. So pushing to the git branch is deployment rather than storage.

Comment: Obviously this use case is Github specific. The main case I see for pushing back to git is pushing tags following a successful release build. I can't think of other use cases involving pushing to branches tbh

Comment: Understood (joanis made the same point about github-pages and generated documentation). I think GitHub are doing this wrong myself, but it's understandable why they do that, and it's not a big deal when what's being generated is textual documentation. It's still "wrong" in a philosophical sense, though (I'd argue anyway).

Comment: Look at this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18936804 - you should find the answer there. Other than that, I agree with @torek point of view.